# Mysql with multiple in clauses and count

Tags: mysql

I have the following sql query:

```
SELECT field_number, COUNT(*) AS c FROM lead_detail WHERE field_number < 3 AND field_number > 2 AND lead_id IN (147,146,145,127,113) GROUP BY field_number
```

It returns:

```
field_number    c
2.1          5
2.2             5
2.3             1
2.4             1
2.5             5
```

I only want to display some fields according to user selection so i used:

```
SELECT field_number, COUNT(*) AS c FROM lead_detail WHERE field_number < 3 AND field_number > 2 AND lead_id IN (147,146,145,127,113,109,91,65,57,56,49) AND field_number IN (2.1,2.3) GROUP BY field_number
```

But now with this query im getting 0 results. I tried to put AND field_number = 2.1 without success.
Any clue why this is happening or how i can avoid this?
lead_id id`s dont have all field_numbers , i think this maybe is the reason. For example in lead_id 147 we can find field_numbers 2.1 and 2.3 and in lead_id 146 we find 2.4 and 2.5
Thanks for the great help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have a typo error in your query it suppose to be`COUNT(*) AS c`
also you have two unnecessary statements there use `field_number < 3 AND field_number > 2` or `field_number IN (2.1,2.3)`
so final query should look like this:

```
SELECT field_number, COUNT(*) AS c 
FROM lead_detail 
WHERE lead_id IN (147,146,145,127,113,109,91,65,57,56,49) 
   AND field_number IN (2.1,2.3)
GROUP BY field_number
```

Comment: Without AS still works, but thanks for pointing the correct sintax. Still giving 0 results tought

Comment: Also have a look on field type of field_number is it VARCHAR or DOUBLE/FLOAT ?

Comment: I found the problem someone changed the field from varchar to float and thats why i wasnt getting any result.

Comment: Hehehe it seems we thought the same thing at the same time. Thanks for your help